# How does iPhone's compass work?

Tags: iphone

How exactly does iPhone's Compass app work? Is there some kind of chip sensitive to Earth's magnetic field or does it deduce the device's orientation from GPS and other location data? Or a combination of both?

If there are differences among different models of iPhone, of course I'd be interested in learning them. Is the iPhone 7 different in this regard?

Comment: Google is your friend! Have a look at: [How does the compass on the iPhone work?](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-compass-on-the-iPhone-work)

Comment: @user3439894: Thanks, very useful! That is from almost five years ago, and covers iPhone 4. Do you happen to know if anything has changed since then?

Comment: Well, I could dig around a bit more on the Internet however you could do the same.  I'd assume there has been improvements in the chips and gyros which have increased/improved accuracy and capability.  Considering that the state of electronics, etc., are constantly improving it's a fair assumption. That said, Apple is, as usual, extremely tight lipid about its electronics, and rightly so.  So if you're looking for more then what was in the link you'll need to do the research.

Comment: @user3439894, I am not sure whether you are suggesting that this question is too easily answerable for this site or requests too much research, but probably in some sense both are actually true.

Comment: Not sure what you want as an answer however the iPhone uses an Electronic Compass IC and software to communicate with the IC, along with the Accelerometer and Gyros also built into the iDevice.  Apple has used more then one type/model Electronic Compass IC since it first introduced its Compass.app to iOS.  If you want more specificity I'd suggest you do some research.

Comment: I personally appreciate this question as it warrants the opinion of an *expert*, not anyone with a google search bar.  I want some technical details on the chip and mechanisms, the software combination of GPS, Magnetometer and Gyros.  I think it is a good question. The Quora answer, is a good example and is great, although is only a piece of the answer a magnetometer, not necessarily a full compass. How does one orient three of these sensors in XYZ axes - is that difficult given the space constraints?

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone 5s Compass app reacts to a magnet.  This proves that it uses a magnetic sensor.

Comment: I have tested this too and can confirm it works on iPhone 7, iPhone 3GS, and iPhone 6.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of online speculation on this, and some of it is laughable. Disclaimer: I use Apple products, but otherwise have no affiliation and know nothing with certainty. But, I have a very strong hunch that the the iPhone in all versions uses a device called a [magnetometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer) for the compass. ICYI, the compass reading is combined with inertial data generated by accelerometers in the iPhone and GPS data from its receiver (when available) to calculate the phone's position using a technique known as Kalman filtering.